# Checksum of large files in nodejs

Tags: node.js, checksum, sha256

I am in the process of writing a script to make a database of my pictures. I have a script that sort of works. It goes through a folder with 5,670 files totalling 13.08 GB of data in 9 minutes and 24 seconds. Then I try it on newer, larger photos the execution seems to decrease drastically. Within 20 minutes is has only calculated the hash of three small preview files in a folder with 431 files totalling 7.58 GB.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var fs = require('fs')
var crypto = require('crypto')
var util = require('util')
var p = require('path')
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./sqlite.db')
const hash_algorithm = 'sha256'

var fileCount = 0

function getFiles(directory) {
    fs.readdir(directory, function(err, files) {
        for (var i in files) {
            var filepath = directory + '/' + files[i]
            fileStat(filepath)
        }
    })
}

function fileStat(filepath) {
    fs.stat(filepath, function(err, stats) {
        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            getFiles(filepath)
        } else {
            computeHash(filepath, hash_algorithm, function(err, hash) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err
                }
                insertStat(filepath, hash, stats.size)
            })
        }
    })
}

function computeHash(filepath, algorithm, callback) {
    var hash = crypto.createHash(algorithm)
    var rs = fs.createReadStream(filepath)

    rs.on('open', function() {})

    rs.on('error', function(err) {
        throw err
    })

    rs.on('data', function(chunk) {
        hash.update(chunk)
    })

    rs.on('end', function() {
        hash = hash.digest('hex')
        return callback(null, hash)
    })
}

function getExif(filepath, callback) {

}

function insertStat(filepath, hash, size) {
    var sql = "INSERT INTO files VALUES ($filename, $path, $hash, $size)"
    var filename = filepath.split('/')
    filename = filename[filename.length - 1]
    db.run(sql, {$filename: filename, $path: filepath, $hash: hash, $size: size})
    if (verbose) console.log('%s: %s', ++fileCount, filepath)
}

db.serialize(function() {
    db.run('CREATE TABLE files (filename text, path text, hash text, size integer)')
})

var verbose = true
var path = process.argv[2] || '.'
path = p.resolve(path)

if (verbose) console.log('path: %s', path)
getFiles(path)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All your process is asynchronous. While it's good practice in javascript, you should keep control of your memory consumption:

1. You start opening your files asynchronously with `fs.stat`. Which means ALL your files.
2. Then you load them in memory using buffers, but you can't start processing them until they're completely loaded an hit the `on('end',..)`. Which means ALL your files are competing to be FULLY loaded in your RAM.

Got it? Your memory usage is 100% and you have to hope a file got fully loaded and processed to release some memory for another one. That's what you're doing wrong.

So you need to get your memory usage back under control. Ideally, you should control how many files are processed at once. As a quick fix, I suggest you make it synchronous with `fs.statSync`.

---

*Side notes*

Your process also involves a database. That's the usual suspect for performance. Your code must log any db error. Here I see no potential deadlock or full scan. So no worries. Just make sure your table `files` is created before you start inserting.

Never use `for..in` to loop into an array. Use `array.forEach()` instead.

Please use semi-colons `;` in your code. Yes, JavaScript most of the time can do without, but it will avoid you weird bugs and ease interpreter's job.

Comment: With both fs.readdir and the computeHash function being async, how would just using fs.statSync instead of fs.stat solve the problem?

I can use fs.readdirSync and fs.statSync. However, I do not understand how to implement the file reading and hashing parts synchronously.

Comment: Fair point. You'd also replace `fs.createReadStream` by a `fs.readFileSync`. Anyway, reading buffer does not make sense in your case: you need the full file before processing. `fs.readdir` can remain async.

Comment: Thank you. With your input do I now have some working code. However, I do not get what you mean by it not making sense to use a reading buffer. When hitting big files I would not like to load the entire file before computing the hash. I guess I somehow need to read a stream blocking.

Hash.update() works well with a stream.

Comment: What's the problem with `for..in`? Why to use `array.forEach()` instead? Please elaborate!

Comment: @SebastianBarth Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/8122487). `for..in` is made to loop over own properties, then properties of prototype chain. It works on arrays too, but are you sure you know what you are doing?

Comment: I would rather say use `for` instead. Of course you must know that you are using an array. `forEach()` is [much slower](https://jsperf.com/fast-array-foreach) than `for` (probably due to method calls).

Comment: @SebastianBarth if you're fond of `for in` you could always use its newer alternative `for of` instead.

Comment: Instead of `array.forEach()`  use `array.map()` 3-5x faster